# Font Awesome icons with class "fa-brands" don't work

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have imported a font awesome library in the header as

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and I have in the body

```html
<i class="fa-brands fa-medium"></i>
```

which does not render (is blank). I am trying to get the icon from [this library](https://fontawesome.com/icons/medium?f=brands&s=solid),
but if I omit `brands` I get a different medium icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading a very old version of Font Awesome (4.7.0) but the documentation you link to is for the current version (6.3.0).

See [Upgrade from version 4](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/upgrade-from-v4) which says:

> ```
>   <!-- Version 4's syntax -->
>   <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> 
>
>   <!-- Version 6's syntax -->
>   <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-retro"></i>
> ```

`fa-brands` is the icon style syntax that was introduced after the version of Font Awesome you are using was released.

Upgrade to the current version.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `fa` class:

```
<i class="fa fa-brands fa-medium"></i>
```

Comment: Typo questions should not be answered, but closed. If you want answer, use comments.

Comment: Why? The documentation the OP linked to doesn't.